# How to restore a mistakenly deleted item in Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

If someone deleted an item  mistakenly in Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET, how can I restore  it?

Comment: Are you using source control integration?  Have you checked the recycle bin?

Comment: Well if you delete it within visual studio you can just add it to the project again. It's not really deleting, it's excluding it from your project.

Comment: If it's really deleted, you can't restore it. That's why I use backups. Cobian timed backups, SVN or Team Foundation for source control, Dropbox for real-time backups.

Comment: what is the source control integration? and i don't have any idea if ther is any  recycle bin in visual studio

Comment: Define "deleted". Do you mean "deleted from project"? Or "deleted physical file from disk"?

Comment: No the general recycle bin on the machine.

Comment: i mean deleted from the progect within visual studio
// and the StyleSheet item is deleted from the content folder too :'(

Comment: the ansewer : i found it in my recycle bin // tnksssss friends